# Callback functions are not called in Android Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am integrating Facebook Login. I have done developing Facebook Login once before. When I develop this time, Facebook callback functions are not called. I cannot check the error as well. I have no idea with what is wrong.

I installed Facebook SDK using Gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

Then I generated key hash and set in the Facebook developer settings as follows:

[image]

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tonightfootballreport.com.tfr" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="tonightfootballreport.model.TfrApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:name=".FacebookConfigActivity"
            android:label="Facebook"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="tonightfootballreport.com.tfr.FacebookConfigActivity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1817380365215100"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see Facebook Login is not in main activity and so I set FacebookConfigActivity in Developer Settings.

Then when I click a button in MainActivity, FacebookConfigActivity will be opened and perform Facebook Login. Below is the code.

```
public class FacebookConfigActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), AppConfig.FACEBOOK_REQUEST_CODE);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);
        setUpCallBack();
        loginInToFacebook();
    }


    private void loginInToFacebook()
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FacebookConfigActivity.this,Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
    }

    private void setUpCallBack()
    {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                //show share alert
                //then share
                Log.i("LOGIN_SUCCESS","LOGIN_SUCCESS");
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Operation canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error in connecting to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is just simple Facebook Login. So when I click login button, I enter credentials to the Facebook Login form you can see below.

[image]

Then after I click OK in the next step, FacebookConfigActivity is displayed and no callback function is called. If I click cancel, Facebook Cancel callback is not called as well. What is the possible error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to put listener in onActivityResult()

put below code in onActivityResult method of activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Oh ya. Thank so much,